# Azure failing to run python script

Tags: python, azure, flask

I built a simple web app using Flask. What this does is basically take data from  a form and sends a POST - which is then passed as a command line argument to the script using

```
os.popen("python3 script.py " + postArgument).read()
```

The command is stored in a variable which is then passed to an element in a new page with the results.

**About the script:** It runs the string in the POST through an API, gets some data, processes it, sends it to another API and finally prints the results (which are finally stored in the variable)

It works fine on a local server. But Azure fails to return anything. The string is empty.

**How do I get some terminal logs?**

**Is there a solution?**

Comment: Does just trying to run `python3` work in your Azure VM? Is there any reason why you don't use `script.py` as a module inside of your existing script instead of starting a new binary / process outside of your existing one?

Comment: @MatsLindh Sorry for my incomprehension. Why don't you handle the post data using Flask if it comes from a form via http post request?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT The POST data is handled by Flask. The point is how do I get the output of the script back to the web page

Comment: @KalolParty I don't understand why not embeded the content of the `script.py` in the handler for the post data to process the data and get the output for rendering the web page. Could you show me your codes which include `script.py` & the post data handler?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, it seems that the issue was caused by the Python 3 (even for Python 2) interpreter called `python` on Azure, not `python3`.

So if you had configured the Python 3 runtime environment for the Application settings on Azure portal as the figure below, please using `python script.py` instead of `python3 script.py` in your code.

[image]

Or you also can use the absolute path of Python 3 on Azure WebApp `D:\Python34\python` instead of `python3` in your code, as below.

[image]

However, I also doubt the another possible issue for you besides the above case. You may use some python packages which be not install using `pip` on Azure. If so, you need to refer to the section [`Troubleshooting - Package Installation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-create-deploy-flask-app#troubleshooting---package-installation) of the Azure offical document for Python to resolve the possible issue.

Hope it helps. Any concern & update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: None of these seem to work. Is there any other way I could run the script and pass the post data to it as a parameter?